# How to get the WebcamTexture of the camera in Kudan AR (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, augmented-reality, kudan

I am currently developing an AR application and I need to get the color of the object from the camera. I need to get the webcamtexture of the camera but I don't know how because Kudan AR has it's own camera. Do you have any idea how to do this? Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a webcam texture and play it then you can create a texture2D and getpixels of the webcame textures to get your colors.

```
 WebCamTexture cam;

// Open the Camera on the desired device / pc cam 
    cam = new WebCamTexture();
    cam.Play();
   currentTexture =new Texture2D(cam.width, cam.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
```

to get the webcam pixels you can do something like

```
       cam.GetPixels();
```